# How to use form validation in a form with a zone attribute?

Tags: forms, validation, tapestry, zone

I have a big problem with Tapestry 5.3.6..

I have a form with a custom simple mixins that implies that form's ids couldnt' be modified :/

So i have this :

```
<form t:type="form" t:id="formId" t:mixins="aMixins" t:zone="zoneID">
    <t:errors/>
    <input t:type="TextField"/>
    <a t:type="LinkSubmit" t:id="linkId"/>
</form>

<t:zone t:id="zoneID">
      Something....
</t:type>
```

When I use the zone form attribute, the validation errors aren't displayed, how can i make the validation errors displays errors without include the form into a zone ?

I can't include this form into a zone because when my mixin is initialized, it put some listeners on some DOM elements and when i submit my form, the form is reloaded (because of the zone) and reload the mixin too, which add some more listener on new DOM elements and after the submit an event is fired which is catched by corresponding listeners, but some of listeners are linked to unexistant elements and the js crash.

Thanks a lot for your reponses

Comment: if you use fixed id for form zone parameter you should also define fixed id for zone: `<t:zone t:id="zoneID" id="zoneID">`

Comment: It does not solve my problem :/

Answer (score 0):

1 .

> I have a form with a custom simple mixins that implies that form's ids
>   couldnt' be modified

This is not implied. Maybe, it's your requirement?

If not then to plug in your mixin into ajax rendering you need to make the mixin a bit more flexible.

In YourMixin class:

```
@InjectContainer
private ClientElement element;

void afterRender() {

    String elementId = element.getClientId();

    JSONObject spec = new JSONObject();
    spec.put("elementId", elementId);

    jsSupport.addScript("new MixinHandler(%s)", spec.toString());
}
```

This is just a hint, take a look at Autocomplete implementation (class, javascript) for a complete sample.

2 .

> When I use the zone form attribute, the validation isn't working

This sounds doubtful.. I guess validation errors are not visible because you do not update the form itself and its `<t:errors/>` tag.

This can be verified if you set break points into FAILURE and SUCCESS event handlers of the form in your page (see org.apache.tapestry5.EventConstants).

Comment: It's the real problem sorry i'm french :/ validation works but I can't render the error component because only the zone is refreshed, I don't know if make the mixin more flexible could solve my problem because when the form is loading, the mixin initializes itself and bind some javascript event and when I submit the form, the mixin initializes itself one more time and bind with same events and after the submit is successful an event is fired and traped by 2 listeners and one of theses listeners is linked to an element which not exist anymore, I refresh my first post to precise my problem

Comment: I guess it would be better to include update not touching the initial part because my answer sounds unrelated now.. Try reviewing tapestry5 javascript to find out if there is some javascript event that fired before sending ajax request - there you can try to unregister the current listeners that will become obsolete.

Comment: I think this is it: `Tapestry.FORM_PROCESS_SUBMIT_EVENT: "tapestry:formprocesssubmit"`